# c# string confusion

Tags: c#, string

I am fairly new to C# and am confused about something.....

Let me show you whats happening and hopefully you guys can tell me what im doing wrong here.

```
string incomming = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
//MessageBox.Show(incomming); shows me the string "stop", No problem

executeCommand(incomming);

public void executeCommand(string action)
{
    MessageBox.Show(action + " was recieved"); // shows the string "stop", No  problem here... that works

    switch (action)
    { 
        case "start":
            MessageBox.Show("start was recieved"); //shows nothing
            break;

        case "stop":
             MessageBox.Show("stop was recieved"); //shows nothing
             break;
    }            
}
```

Comment: Are the cases even being reached? Set a breakpoint and check.

Comment: Are you sure there's no `\n` in action?

Comment: Well... what's the string in question?

Comment: when you switch on action, what is action?

Comment: Yes, especially if you are getting output, what is the actual output of: `action + " was recieved"`

Comment: As @Tung suggested, can you try running a Trim() and see if that works, as this should work

Comment: From what I see, there must be a hidden character, like a space on the end of the string.

Comment: Justin, the actual out put of action is "stop", all lower case no quotes.

Comment: @LeenBalsters The problem is that if that's the case, the code you've shown us here should work.

Comment: @LeenBalsters, if there is a `\n`, you will still just see "stop", but the strings will not be equivalent

Comment: Is there a syntax error after switch? `switch (`, `switch(`

Comment: add This code after your last case statement:

default:   MessageBox.Show("|" + action + "|"); break;

If what you're saying is true, it should show "|stop|". Also, if what you're saying is true, the universe should end.

Comment: Or better yet check the length of `action`

Comment: All this would be avoided if you learned how to use breakpoints, the Immediate or Watch window, or even hovered over the parameter with your mouse.

Comment: aquinas, that returned |stop and not |stop| making me think other are right. there must something hiding. the string comes from a PHP client. $in = "stop"; socket_write($socket, $in, strlen($in));

Comment: just so you guys know. if i do an is statement to see if action = "stop" then i also get false

Answer (score 1):

With out knowing what the contents of the Byte array that is being converted to a String it is very hard to give you anything help you. But here are a few things to try.

1. You can put a breakpoint on `executeCommand(incomming)` and in your watch window type `incomming.ToCharArray()`, you will need to click on the green circle in the value column before you can see the characters that are apart of the string. This should let you know what you are dealing with.
   [image]
2. You can search incomming for a match of the string you are looking for by using the [String.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) Method.

---

```
if (action.Contains("stop"))
    MessageBox.Show("stop was recieved");
else if (action.Contains("start"))
    MessageBox.Show("start was recieved");
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reasonable explanation for this is that one of your "stop" strings has a letter in a diferent language from english but looks the same. In this case:

```
"stop" != "stоp"
```

is true;